# 301 redirects for pages with <a name> bookmarks

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

We are rebuilding our current retail site (art re-sellers) which uses internal bookmarks for much of the links ie products on a hub page that link to the details for that product on another page with 15 items. So 60 products show on a hub page, each cluster of 15 go to a detail page, broken up with 15 book marks.

In setting up 301 redirect, does it make sense to redirect each URL with its bookmark pointing to that products new individual detail page? For example:

`http://www.example.com/oldpage.html#7` redirects to `http://www.example.com/product7`

OR should `oldpage.html` just be redirected to the new collection page for that category?

All of the 15 products on the page are in the same category but are one of a kind and change often but use the same link from the hub page. The pages are ranked very well for the categories, but not necessarily for the more detailed searches. Obviously when Google returns results based on an individual product, it doesn't use the bookmark so users find the page but still have to scroll down on that page to find the product that triggered the result.

Hopefully that all makes sense. Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1):

> `http://www.example.com/oldpage.html#7` redirects to `http://www.example.com/product7`

From a technical point of view, you are not going to be able to "301 redirect" from `/oldpage.html#7` to `/product7`, since the fragment identifier `#7` is not sent to the server, so you can't respond with a 301 status based on this information.

The best you can do is issue a JavaScript redirect, since the `#7` is only seen client-side. But this is a 200 OK status, not a redirect 3xx status, so search engines will struggle to handle this as intended.